# Flutter: How to use Wrap instead of ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

In `FutureBuilder`, I need to create `Wrap` with elements but I don't know how.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _getCategories(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    if(snapshot.data == null){
      return Text("Wait...");
    }else{
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return  Text(snapshot.data[index].category);
        },
      );
    }
  },
)
```

I need to replace `ListView.builder` with something like `Wrap.builder` or something else.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Let's say this is your `List`:

```dart
List<int> _items = List.generate(10, (i) => i);
```

You can use it in `Wrap`:

1. Using **`List.map`**

   ```dart
   Wrap(
     direction: Axis.vertical,
     children: _items.map((i) => Text('Item $i')).toList(),
   )
   ```
2. Using **`for-each`**

   ```dart
   Wrap(
     direction: Axis.vertical,
     children: [
       for (var i in _items)
         Text('Item $i'),
     ],
   )
   ```

---

To answer your question:

```
Wrap(
  children: snapshot.data.map((item) => Text(item.category)).toList().cast<Widget>(),
)
```

Comment: It gives error `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'`

Comment: Can you tell me what your `snapshot.data` returns?

Comment: It returns a list of objects

Comment: Yes, I know but what kind of objects, are they actually `Object` and was your code running fine with `ListView.builder` (the current code you posted)?

Comment: this is how my object looks like 
`class CategoryPODO{
  String category;
  int id;

  CategoryPODO({
    this.category,
    this.id
  });
}`

Yes, it works with the code I posted.

Comment: i still getting type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'

Comment: @ASBAHRIYAS Please ask a standalone question, it's difficult to help without seeing your code.

Comment: wow, I didn't know we can call `for` directly inside `list bracket`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution,

```
List tags = ['one','two'];    
Wrap(
          children: [
            for (var item in tags)
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Chip(
                  
                  label: Text(item),
                ),
              )
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Wrap(
       children: snapshot. data.map((e) => CustomCard(data: e,)).toList().cast<Widget>(),
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).