# Is it okay to use an onPressed function in a ChangeNotifier child class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-secure-storage

I am using provider for state management, and I've given onTap a value in a function in the ChangeNotifier child class but my app is unresponsive, I mean, when i tap on the widget, it doesn't update state, however, it does change the values i need it to change tho, i know this coz I am debugPrinting in the onTap function and when i tap, it actually prints that the button got tapped, but state doesn't update, widget remains the same until i hot restart, then it updates everything, even hot reload doesn't update it, here's the function

```
class Storage extends ChangeNotifier{

  static const _storage =  FlutterSecureStorage();
  static const _listKey = 'progress';
  List _dataMaps = [];
  List<DayTile> dayTileMain = [];

  void createDataMap() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
      final data = Data(number: i).toJson();
      _dataMaps.add(data);
    }
  }

  void createDayTiles() {
    for(Map<String, dynamic> data in _dataMaps) {
      bool isDone = data['i'];
      final dayTile = DayTile(
        number: data['n'],
        isDone: isDone,
        // This is where i need to rebuild the tree
        onTap: () async {
          data['i'] = true;
          notifyListeners();
          print(data['i']);
          print(isDone);
          await writeToStorage();
        },
      );
      dayTileMain.add(dayTile);
    }
    print('data tiles created');
  }
}
```

and here is the DayTile class

```
class DayTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const DayTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.number,
    required this.isDone,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int number;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final bool isDone;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .15,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: !isDone
              ? const Color(0xffedecea)
              : const Color(0xffedecea).withOpacity(0.1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  number.toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff576aa4),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: isDone,
                child: const Divider(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is where I listen for the change

```
Wrap(
      spacing: 13,
      runSpacing: 13,
      children: Provider.of<Storage>(context).dayTileMain,
   ),
```

when `data['i']` is true, it should update the current instance of DayTile() that it's on in the loop, and in `DayTile()` I use the value of `data['i']` to set the value of `bool isDone` and depending on whether isDone is true or false, the color of the widget changes and some other things, BUT, they don't change onTap, but they change after I hot restart, when it's read the storage and restored the saved data, could the secureStorage writing to storage at the same time be affecting it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, turns out it's not a good idea to listen for events in the model class, it won't listen, so instead of generating the list of widgets in the model class, I moved it outta there, and instead generated it inside the wrap widget, and instead of listening for a list in the model class, i just had the list there in my wrap, if it was a listview i was tryna generated, i would've done this initially with a `ListView.builder()` i didn't know you could generate a list inside the children of the wrap widget, so i just stuck to defining it in the model, I came across this stack question [Flutter: How to use Wrap instead of ListView.builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58547544/17971158)
and that's how i knew how to build widgets inside a children property, i was actually just looking for a `ListView.builder()` version for the Wrap widget, all said, this is what my stuff is looking like

**Model**

```
class Storage extends ChangeNotifier {
  static const _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  static const _listKey = 'progress';
  List _dataMaps = [];
  List<DayTile> dayTileMain = [];

  void createDataMap() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
      final data = Data(number: i).toJson();
      _dataMaps.add(data);
    }
  }

  int get listLength {
    return _dataMaps.length;
  }

  UnmodifiableListView get dataMaps {
    return UnmodifiableListView(_dataMaps);
  }

  void pressed(Map<String, dynamic> map) async {
    map['i'] = true;
    await writeToStorage();
    notifyListeners();
  }


  Future writeToStorage() async {
    final value = json.encode(_dataMaps);
    await _storage.write(key: _listKey, value: value);
  }

  Future<void> getTasks() async {
    print('getTasks called');
    final value = await _storage.read(key: _listKey);
    final taskList = value == null ? null : List.from(jsonDecode(value));
    if (taskList == null) {
      print('getTasks is null');
      createDataMap();
      // createDayTiles();
    } else {
      print('getTasks is not null');
      print(taskList);
      _dataMaps = taskList;
      // createDayTiles();
    }
  }

  Future readFromStorage() async {
    await getTasks();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Wrap Builder**

```
class DayTiles extends StatelessWidget {
  const DayTiles({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Storage>(
      builder: (_, storageData, __) => Wrap(
        spacing: 13,
        runSpacing: 13,
        children: [
          for(Map<String, dynamic> data in storageData.dataMaps)
            DayTile(
              number: data['n'],
              onTap: () {
                storageData.pressed(data);
              },
              isDone: data['i'],
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and instead of using a wrap and listening for changes to it's children in the screen class, i just directly use the `DayTiles()` custom widget i created