# Flutter - How to center list of word and move the extended word in a row to next line

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a list of single word in a page, I want to know how to center these words and move the extended word in a row to next line, as shown in Image 2
This is Image 1, which I use gridview, but I cannot center the words, and the number of the word in each row is fix.
[image]

Below is Image 2, this is the result I want to get. Instead of using GridView widget, is there any other option to do?
[image]

Below are the code:

```
Expanded(
child: FutureBuilder<WordModel>(
  future: alphabetsList(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.words.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Wrap(
            alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                  child: Text(
                    snapshot.data.words[index].name.toString(),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
      );
    } 
  },
),
```

Comment: Please add some code of what you've tried to easily understand your thought process

Comment: Are those words individually tappable or are just for display?

Comment: Hi @Roslan Amir, it is tappable

Comment: Hey, The easy solution that comes to my mind is to use listview instead of gridview and then define a text widget inside the centre widget, you can make it tappable by using a gesture detector. Also it would be much easier if you can include your code

Comment: Like @Davis says, show your current code which you use to produce the first screenshot.

Comment: Hi I have included a sample code, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Wrap` for that. For example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  final list = [
    "Apple",
    "Balloon",
    "Cake",
    "Dog",
    "Egg",
    "Flamingo",
    "Grape",
    "House",
    "Ice-Cream",
    "Jellyfish",
    "Kite",
    "Lemon",
    "Mouse",
    "Nose"
  ];

  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
    body: Wrap(alignment: WrapAlignment.center, children: [
      for (String s in list)
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
          child: Text(
            s,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
          ),
        )
    ]),
  )));
}
```

Output:

[image]

EDIT:

with your code it could be something like this:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  return Wrap(alignment: WrapAlignment.center, children: [
  for (final word in snapshot.data.words)
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
      child: Text(
        word.name.toString()
      ),
    )
   ]);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ivo, it almost get what I need. How about if I need to use the builder because the list of string is populated from nosql database. So I have to use ListView.builder - itemCount, itemBuilder etc. How to use Wrap widget together with ListView or Gridview builder?

Comment: I added a sample code I am writing, can you have a look

Comment: @JovenDev just use `snapshot.data.words` instead of my `list`

Comment: @JovenDev see my edit

Comment: Hi @Ivo, checked, it worked. Another question, how to make it scrollable to bottom?

Comment: Maybe you can wrap it in a `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

try the `Wrap` widget: [Like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5iw2SeFx2M)

and if you want to implement this with listView: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58547544/flutter-how-to-use-wrap-instead-of-listview-builder)

Comment: Hi, I added my code, can you have a look? How to modify it in order to get the result I need?